# rythmengine CompileException "annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater"

Tags: rythm

I'm calling rythmengine with Java 1.8, compiled and executed via Gradle.

Here's the exception:

org.rythmengine.exception.CompileException: Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

...

### Relevant Java source lines:

```
   2: import org.rythmengine.template.TemplateBase;
   3: import java.io.*;
   4: 
   5: public class C73bd49e7_ca2e_33dd_a822_07d30e7f8c26__R_T_C__ extends org.rythmengine.template.TagBase {
   6: 
>> 7:   @Override public java.lang.String __getName() {
   8:       return "C73bd49e7_ca2e_33dd_a822_07d30e7f8c26__R_T_C__";
   9:   }
   10: 
   11: 
   12:  protected java.lang.String __renderArgName(int __pos) {
   13:      int __p = 0;
```

---

Elsewhere in my code I'm using annotations without any trouble, and I've verified that Gradle really is running JRE 1.8. The problem seems to be happening with Rythm's internal compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Please submit an issue on https://github.com/greenlaw110/rythm/issues. For now add a JVM option `-Djava.version=1.8` when you start gradle

Comment: Thanks, added issue #284. Unfortunately it still happens with -Djava.version=1.8.

Comment: Elsewhere I've seen posts about this issue happening with certain versions of Eclipse, and I noticed rythm seems to use the Eclipse compiler internally, so guessing this might be related. Happy to help with any further info you might need to repro this.

Comment: What is your rythm version?